# Change Button Background in ListView when button is click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I have one listview.which contain one image ,text and one button .i had creted custom listview for that.now i want to change background image of button when button is clicked.i got an click event in getView method of my CustomAdapter.but i m not able to change the background image.
please help me.

following is my code of getView() method of adapter.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_lv_operator, null); 
    tvOperatorname=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvOperatorName);
    ivOperatorIcon=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivOperatorIcon);
    btnAddToFavourite=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnFavourite);
    tvOperatorname.setText(values[position]);
    ivOperatorIcon.setImageResource(icons[position]);
    //holder.ivOperatorIcon.setTag(values[position]);
    btnAddToFavourite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {                           
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
                **btnAddToFavourite.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favourite_marked));**
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    eturn v; 
}
```

Comment: instead of btnAddToFavourite.setBackgroundDrawable try arg0.setBackgroundDrawable

Comment: Thanks my friend...its working..thanks 4 guiding me...god bless you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what your trying to do is something like

```
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
((Button) arg0).setBackgroundDrawable(....
```

well.. if im not mistaken View class also have setBackgroundDrawable but the idea is you should use the onclicked view and not the general btnAddToFavourite

Comment: +1 - but if the list got scrolled the color will change. or give odd result, in case he'll use `ViewHolder`

Comment: thank you so much my friend......keep helping..i got the solution..god bless you...